# BigQueryIO.Write load jobs for streaming pipeline in Apache Beam / Adding fields to a BigQuery Table in streaming Dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read messages from Pub/Sub using a global window of 5 seconds, transform and validate them using a certain Beam schema and write their content into a BigQuery table using Dataflow. I am able to achieve it by using the STREAMING_INSERTS method available for the BigQueryIO.Write. My problem is the following: whenever the message schema might change, because new columns are added to it, I would like to still be able to expand the destination table schema from inside Dataflow. However, SchemaUpdateOptions are only available in case of FILE_LOADS method and not for STREAMING_INSERTS.

```
PCollection<String> messagesFromPubSub = pipeline
                .apply(PubsubIO.readMessagesWithCoderAndParseFn(StringUtf8Coder.of(), 
                       new MyParserFn()).fromSubscription(subscription)
                .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(5))));

JsonToRow.ParseResult parsedMessages = messagesFromPubSub.apply( 
                                JsonToRow.withExceptionReporting(beamSchema).withExtendedErrorInfo());

PCollection<Row> parsedMessagesGood = parsedMessages.getResults();
```

How I write the rows with STREAMING_INSERTS:

```
parsedMessagesGood.apply(WRITE_BQ, BigQueryIO.<Row>write()
                .to(bqPath)
                .withSchema(bqSchema)
                .withCustomGcsTempLocation(ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider.of(tmpLocation))
                .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                .withWriteDisposition(WRITE_APPEND)
                .useBeamSchema()
                .withMethod(STREAMING_INSERTS);
```

I've tried to insert new rows into my destination table using FILE_LOADS method and withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardSeconds(2)) as it is suggested in the documentation.

```
        Set<BigQueryIO.Write.SchemaUpdateOption> schemaUpdateOptions = new      HashSet<BigQueryIO.Write.SchemaUpdateOption>();
        schemaUpdateOptions.add(ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION);


        parsedMessagesGood.apply(WRITE_BQ, BigQueryIO.<Row>write()
                .to(bqPath)
                .withSchema(bqSchema)
                .withCustomGcsTempLocation(ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider.of(tmpLocation))
                .withCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                .withWriteDisposition(WRITE_APPEND)
                .useBeamSchema()
                .withSchemaUpdateOptions(schemaUpdateOptions)
                .withMethod(FILE_LOADS)
                .withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardSeconds(2));
```

Besides this main flow a have also 2 secondary ones, where in one I write the faulty messages in a separate data quality table, but it mirrors the same BigQueryIO.Write strategy and the other one I also push the messages into a PubSub topic. As said before, the whole system works with STREAMING_INSERTS, but not with FILE_LOADS.

However I get a simple "Error processing pipeline." log in Cloud Monitoring without any additional information. How can I approach differently this problem? Thank you!

Comment: From the `Dataflow` job, what are the error in job logs, workers logs and diagnostics please ?

Comment: The only error I get is "Error processing pipeline." in job logs without any other error trace or additional information. Worker logs are empty since the pipeline, I guess, failed to build.

Comment: I also found a warning "Unbounded PCollection(s) found in a batch pipeline! You might consider using 'streaming=true'!". However, I have " --enable-streaming-engine" set in my configurations.

Comment: Note that `--enable-streaming-engine` is different than `--streaming=true`. `Error processing pipeline` might be some feature incompatibility / Proto translation. I would check any experiments that you are using. If stuck, suggest filing a Google Cloud support ticket with a job id so this can be looked further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of an underlying limitation in the BQ APIs. STREAMING_INSERTS  doesn't have schema_update_options, so it isn't supported at the Beam layer either.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#add_columns_when_you_overwrite_or_append_data has the documentation for what this looks like for FILE_LOADS, and there aren't equivalent options for STREAMING_INSERTS